# Open a local file providing a hyperlink in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, hyperlink

I need to open a local file by providing a hyperlink in visualforce page.

**Note:** 
By using html file the local file is opening.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="file:///home/gss/Desktop/sample data_1.csv">Link 1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any sort of option available in salesforce for opening a file stored in local machine.

Any ideas please suggest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally we need to use the `file:///` protocol (three slashes) to link to local files.

```
<a href="file:///C:\Programs\file1.txt">Local file 1</a>
<a href="file:///C:\Videos\SalesforceCI.mp4">Local file 2</a>
```

However, because of security reasons it is disabled by most of browser. If you try to open local file, you will get an error in JavaScript console :

```
Not allowed to load local resource:<file path>
```

As per my analysis, It is not possible to open local file from Salesforce

Below image show console error
[image]

Comment: I have tried this earlier...   <a href="file:///C:\Users\Test\Desktop\link.xml">Local file 2</a>   but not opening

Comment: That's right. I tried it and couldn't open. Have updated my answer with detail.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error and have resolved it.

My visualforce:

```
<apex:outputPanel>

<a href="file:///C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\share">Open</a>

</apex:outputPanel>
```

To avoid the "not allowed to load local resource" error, you need to add Trusted Sites in Windows as follows:

[image]